# Word frequency counter - symbol table - array implementation

Tags: algorithm, c, object-oriented

## Symbol table

- It is key-value pair abstraction
- Insert a value with specified key
- Given a key, search for the corresponding value

---

Here is the design for symbol table implementation for frequency counting of words:

[image]

---

Code directory structure:

```
./Code$
.:
fileIO  list  ST tinyTale type.h frequencyCounter.c frequencyCounter.exe

./fileIO:
file.h  fileReading.c

./list:
arrayImpl.c   config.c virtualImplLayer.c linkedListImpl.c  list.h listHandler.h  listInterface.h  

./ST:
implWithArray.c  ST.h
```

---

Data input:

## tinyTale(data)

```
it was the best of times
it was the worst of times
it was the age of wisdom
it was the age of foolishness
it was the epoch of belief
it was the epoch of incredulity
it was the season of light
it was the season of darkness
it was the spring of hope
it was the winter of despair
```

---

## type.h

```
/********* type.h ********/

 #include<stdbool.h>
 #include<stddef.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<time.h>
```

---

## list.h

```
/************ list.h ************/

/*
   List is an ordered collection of homogenuous type elements(unique or duplicate).
   List is not designed to have collection of heterogenuous type elements
   All elements in a List are related.
   List is mutable
   Each element has a position.
   If an element is deleted, then still the remaining elements sit in new order.

   Array implementation of List
   Linked implementation of List
*/

#ifndef LIST_H /* Header guard */
#define LIST_H
#include"type.h"

/***************** Usage-start ************/



  /* To ensure Encapsulation(i.e., maintain invariants of array & linked list)
     So, Just provide the `List` declartion, to avoid mis-use of `List`
  */
  typedef struct List List;



 typedef int (*compareTo)(const void *, const void *);
 typedef bool (*isLess)(const void *, const void *);
 typedef bool (*isEqual)(const void *, const void *);

#endif
```

---

## listHandler.h

```
/***********listHandler.h ***********/
#ifndef LISTHANDLER_H
#define LISTHANDLER_H

#include"list/list.h"
typedef struct {

         bool(*canHandle)(char*);
        List*(*createList)(void);
         void(*freeList)(List*);
         void(*swim)(List*, int, isLess);
         void(*sink)(List*, int, isLess);
        void*(*listDeleteMaxElement)(List*, isLess);
        void*(*sortedListDeleteMaxElement)(List*);
          int(*listGetSize)(List*);
  const void*(*listGetItem)(List*, const int);
        List*(*sortedListInsertItem)(List*, void*, compareTo);
         void(*listInsertItem)(List*, void*);
        void*(*listDeleteItem)(List*, int);
        void*(*listDeleteLastItem)(List*);
        void*(*listDeleteFirstItem)(List*);
         int(*linearSearch)(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo);
        void*(*binarySearch)(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo);
         void(*insertionSort)(List*, size_t, isLess);
         void(*mergeSort)(List*, size_t, isLess);
         void(*swap)(List*, int, int);

}ListHandler;

/*
  "config.c" lookup below 2 global symbols created in impl handlers,
   before linking time, so "extern" keyword
*/
extern ListHandler arrayImplHandler;
extern ListHandler linkedListImplHandler;

/*
  "viml.c" lookup below global symbol created in "config.c",
   before linking time, so "extern" keyword
*/
extern ListHandler *listHandlers[];

/* Prototypes for definitions in viml.c - start ********/
        List* vCreateList(char *);
         void vFreeList(List*, char *);
         void vSwim(List*, int, isLess, char *);
         void vSink(List*, int, isLess, char *);
        void* vListDeleteMaxElement(List*, isLess, char *);
        void* vSortedListDeleteMaxElement(List*, char *);
          int vListGetSize(List*, char *);
  const void* vListGetItem(List*, const int, char *);
        List* vSortedListInsertItem(List*, void*, compareTo, char *);
         void vListInsertItem(List*, void*, char *);
        void* vListDeleteItem(List*, int, char *);
        void* vListDeleteLastItem(List*, char *);
        void* vListDeleteFirstItem(List*, char *);
          int vLinearSearch(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo, char *);
        void* vBinarySearch(const void*, List*, size_t, compareTo, char *);
         void vInsertionSort(List*, size_t, isLess, char *);
         void vMergeSort(List*, size_t, isLess, char *);
         void vSwap(List*, int, int, char *);
/*****End ***********************************************/

#endif
```

---

## listInterface.h

```
#include"list/listHandler.h"

#ifndef LISTINTERFACE_H
#define LISTINTERFACE_H

/*********** User Interface - start *****************/
#define createList()                   vCreateList(argv[1])
#define freeList(a)                    vFreeList(a, argv[1])
#define swim(a, b, c)                  vSwim(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define sink(a, b, c)                  vSink(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define deleteMax(a, b)                vListDeleteMaxElement(a, b, argv[1])
#define sortDeleteMax(a)               vSortedListDeleteMaxElement(a, argv[1])
#define getSize(a)                     vListGetSize(a, argv[1])
#define getItem(a, b)                  vListGetItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define sortInsertItem(a, b, c)        vSortedListInsertItem(a, argv[1])
#define insertItem(a, b)               vListInsertItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define deleteItem(a, b)               vListDeleteItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define deleteLastItem(a)              vListDeleteLastItem(a, argv[1])
#define deleteFirstItem(a)             vListDeleteFirstItem(a, argv[1])
#define lSearch(a, b, c, d)            vLinearSearch(a, b, c, d, argv[1])
#define bSearch(a, b ,c, d)            vBinarySearch(a, b, c, d, argv[1])
#define callInsertionSort(a, b, c)     vInsertionSort(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define callMergeSort(a, b, c)         vMergeSort(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define swap(a, b, c)                  vSwap(a, b, c, argv[1])

/*********** User Interface - end *****************/
#endif
```

---

## virtualImplLayer.c

```
#include "list/listHandler.h"

/*****Private symbol - start *****************/
static ListHandler * findListImplHandler(char *);
/*****Private symbol - end   *****************/


/***** User interface - start *************/
List* vCreateList(char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);

  if(listHandler != NULL){

    List *list = listHandler->createList();
    return list;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;

}


void vFreeList(List *list, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    listHandler->freeList(list);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}


void vSwim(List *list, int parentIndex, isLess less, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    listHandler->swim(list, parentIndex, less);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}

void vSink(List *list, int index, isLess less, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    listHandler->sink(list, index, less);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}


void* vListDeleteMaxElement(List *list, isLess less, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    return listHandler->listDeleteMaxElement(list, less);
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}

void* vSortedListDeleteMaxElement(List *list, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    return listHandler->sortedListDeleteMaxElement(list);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}


int vListGetSize(List *list, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    return listHandler->listGetSize(list);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return -1;
}


const void* vListGetItem(List *list, const int index, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    return listHandler->listGetItem(list, index);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}

List* vSortedListInsertItem(List *list, void *item, compareTo compare, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    list = listHandler->sortedListInsertItem(list, item, compare);
    return list;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}


void vListInsertItem(List *list, void *item, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){

    listHandler->listInsertItem(list, item);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}

void* vListDeleteItem(List *list, int listIndex, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    return listHandler->listDeleteItem(list, listIndex);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}


void* vListDeleteLastItem(List *list, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    return listHandler->listDeleteLastItem(list);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}


void* vListDeleteFirstItem(List *list, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    return listHandler->listDeleteFirstItem(list);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}

int vLinearSearch(const void *key, List *list, size_t size, compareTo compare, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    return listHandler->linearSearch(key, list, size, compare);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return -1;
}


void* vBinarySearch(const void *key, List *list, size_t size, compareTo compare, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    return listHandler->binarySearch(key, list, size, compare);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
  return NULL;
}

void vInsertionSort(List *list, size_t size, isLess less, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    listHandler->insertionSort(list, size, less);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}


void vMergeSort(List *list, size_t size, isLess less, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    listHandler->mergeSort(list, size, less);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}


void vSwap(List *list, int i, int j, char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *listHandler = findListImplHandler(argvOneOption);
  if(listHandler != NULL){
    listHandler->swap(list, i, j);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "No implementation for this feature\n");
}

/***** User interface -end *************/


/*****Private symbol - start *****************/
static ListHandler * findListImplHandler(char *argvOneOption){

  ListHandler *implHandler = NULL;
  int handlerIndex = 0;
  while(listHandlers[handlerIndex] !=NULL){

    implHandler = listHandlers[handlerIndex];
    if(implHandler->canHandle(argvOneOption)){
      return implHandler;
    }
    handlerIndex++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
/*****Private symbol - end *****************/
```

---

## config.c

```
#include"list/listHandler.h"


ListHandler *listHandlers[] ={

  &arrayImplHandler,
  &linkedListImplHandler,
  NULL // to indicate end of array
};
```

---

## arrayImpl.c

```
/***************** arrayImpl.c **************/


#include"list/listHandler.h" // for 'ListHandler' type

/*
  typedefs are always "local to a file".
  'ListResizeOperation' type is used only in array implementation
*/
typedef enum {DOUBLE_THE_LIST, HALF_THE_LIST}ListResizeOperation;


/****** Private symbols - start - Not visible to Linker*************/
static List *resizeList(List *, ListResizeOperation);
static void *bSearchRecur(const void *, void**, int, int, compareTo);
static void *bSearchIter(const void *, void **, int, int, compareTo);

static void insSort(List *, size_t, isLess);
static void merge(void **, void **, int, int, int, isLess);
static void mSort(void **, void **, int, int, isLess);
static void *delMaxListElem(void **, size_t, isLess);
/****** Private symbols - end ********************/


/*
  Representation - start
  Public symbol with restricted access to user to its details
*/
typedef struct List{

  void **array;

  /* For housekeeping - Array enhancement/shrink */
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;

#define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50
#define FIRST_ITEM_INDEX 0
/********************* Representation - end ************/


/************* Public symbols - start ***************/

bool canArrayImplHandle(char *argvOneOption){
  if(strcmp(argvOneOption, "ARRAY") == 0){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

List *arrayCreate(void){

    List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if(list != NULL){

      list->array = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void*));
      if(list->array != NULL){

        /* Is it safe to initialise zero to  array of  pointers? */
        list->array = memset(list->array, 0, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void *));
        list->lastItemPosition = -1;
        list->size = INITIAL_LIST_SIZE;
      }else{
        free(list);
        list = NULL;
      }
    }

    return list;
}

void arrayFree(List *list){

  if(list != NULL){
    if(list->array != NULL){
      int index = 0;
      while( index <= list->lastItemPosition){
        free(list->array[index++]);
      }
      free(list->array);
    }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid list sent to freeList()\n");
    }
    free(list);
  }
}


int arrayGetSize(List *list){
  if(list != NULL){
    return list->lastItemPosition + 1;
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr, "List is NULL\n ");
    return -1;
  }
}

void *arrayDeleteItem(List *arrayList, int listIndex){

  if(arrayList == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid list \n");
    return NULL;
  }
  void *returnElement = NULL;
  if(listIndex < arrayGetSize(arrayList)){
    returnElement= arrayList->array[listIndex];
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid index\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Delete operation - O(n) operation */
  for(int accumulator = listIndex; accumulator <= arrayList->lastItemPosition; accumulator++){
    arrayList->array[accumulator] = arrayList->array[accumulator + 1];
  }

  arrayList->lastItemPosition--;


  /* House keeping - Half the list */
  if(arrayList->size > INITIAL_LIST_SIZE){ /* Minimum size maintained */
    if((arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1) == ((arrayList->size)/2)){
      arrayList = resizeList(arrayList, HALF_THE_LIST);
      if(arrayList == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "deleteItem() - Unable to allocate memory \n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
  return returnElement; /* User must free this element*/
}

void * arrayDeleteLastItem(List *arrayList){

  return arrayDeleteItem(arrayList, arrayList->lastItemPosition);
}


void *arrayDeleteFirstItem(List *arrayList){

  return arrayDeleteItem(arrayList, FIRST_ITEM_INDEX);
}


void arraySwap(List *list, int i, int j){

  void **array = list->array;

  void *tempPointer = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = tempPointer;
}

void arraySwim(List *list, int index, isLess less){

  void **array = list->array;
  while(index > 1 &&  less(array[index/2], array[index]) ){
    arraySwap(list, index/2, index);
    index/=2;
  }
}


void arraySink(List *list, int parentIndex, isLess less){

  void **array = list->array;
  while( 2*parentIndex <= list->lastItemPosition ){

    int childIndex = 2*parentIndex;
    if( childIndex < list->lastItemPosition && //larger child
                (less(array[childIndex], array[childIndex+1])) ){
      childIndex = childIndex + 1;
    }
    if(!less(array[parentIndex], array[childIndex])) break;
    arraySwap(list, parentIndex, childIndex);
    parentIndex = childIndex;
  }
}



void *arrayDeleteMaxElement(List *list, isLess less){
  if(list != NULL){

    void *maxElement= delMaxListElem(list->array, arrayGetSize(list), less);
    list->lastItemPosition--;
    return maxElement;
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr, "listDeleteMaxElement() - NULL is passed\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  return NULL;
}


void *sortedArrayDeleteMaxElement(List *list){
  if(list != NULL){

    void *maxElement= arrayDeleteLastItem(list);
    return maxElement;
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr, "sortedListDeleteMaxElement() - NULL is passed\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  return NULL;
}

const void *arrayGetItem(List *list, const int index){

  if((index >=0) && (index < arrayGetSize(list))){

    return (const void *)list->array[index];
  }else{
    return NULL;
  }
}


void arrayInsertItem(List *arrayList, void *newItem){

  if(arrayList == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "listInsertItem() -Invalid list \n");
    return;
  }
  /* House keeping - Enhance the array */
  if(arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1 == arrayList->size){
    arrayList = resizeList(arrayList, DOUBLE_THE_LIST);
    if(arrayList == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "insertItem() - Unable to allocate memory \n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }


  /* Insert new element - O(1) operation */
  arrayList->array[++(arrayList->lastItemPosition)] = newItem;

}


List * sortedArrayInsertItem(List *arrayList, void *newItem, compareTo compare){

  if(arrayList == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "listInsertItem() -Invalid list \n");
    return NULL;
  }

  List *newlist = arrayCreate();

  /* Insert new element - O(n) operation */
  int index =0;
  for(; index <= arrayList->lastItemPosition; index++){
    if( compare(newItem, arrayList->array[index]) > 0){

      arrayInsertItem(newlist, arrayList->array[index]);
    }
    arrayList->array[index] = NULL;
  }//end for-loop

  arrayInsertItem(newlist, newItem);

  for(;index <= arrayList->lastItemPosition; index++){
    arrayInsertItem(newlist, arrayList->array[index]);
    arrayList->array[index] = NULL;
  }
  free(arrayList);
  arrayList = newlist;

  return arrayList;
}

/**************Searching & Sorting -start **************/
int arrayLinearSearch(const void *keyItem, List *list, size_t listSize, compareTo compare){

  //printf("arrayLinearSearch() - List size:%d\n", listSize);
  if(list != NULL && (listSize > 0)){
    void ** array = list->array;
    for(int index =0; index < listSize; index++){
      if(compare(keyItem, array[index] ) == 0){
        //printf("Same key\n");
        return index;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}


void *arrayBinarySearch(const void *key, List *list, size_t listSize, compareTo compare){

  if(list != NULL && (listSize > 0)){
    return bSearchIter(key, list->array, 0, listSize-1, compare);
    return bSearchRecur(key, list->array, 0, listSize-1, compare);
  }
  return NULL;
}


void arrayInsertionSort(List *list, size_t listSize, isLess less){

  if(list!=NULL && (listSize > 0)){
    insSort(list, listSize, less);
  }
}


void arrayMergeSort(List *list, size_t listSize, isLess less){

  if(list != NULL){

    void **aux = malloc(arrayGetSize(list) * sizeof(void*)); //Auxillary shadow copy
    if(aux != NULL){
      printf("Size of list: %d\n", listSize);
      mSort(list->array, aux, 0, listSize-1, less);
    }else{

      fprintf(stderr, "mergeSort() - Malloc failure");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "mergeSort() - List is NULL");
  }
}

/****************Public symbols - end *******************/


/* Private symbols - start - Not visible to Linker****/

static void *delMaxListElem(void **array, size_t size, isLess less){

  if(size >0){

    const void *maxElement = array[0];
    int maxElementIndex = 0;
    printf("size of list: %d\n", size);
    for(int index = 1; index < size; index++){
      if( less(maxElement, array[index]) ){
        maxElement = array[index];
        maxElementIndex = index;
      }
    }

    for(int index = maxElementIndex; index < size-1; index++){
      array[index] = array[index+1];// Rearrange array
    }

    return (void *)maxElement;
  }else{
    return NULL;
  }
}


static void mSort(void **array, void **aux, int low, int high, isLess less){

  if(high <= low) return;
  int mid = (low + high)/2;

  mSort(array, aux, low, mid, less);
  mSort(array, aux, mid+1, high, less);
  merge(array, aux, low, mid, high, less);
}


static void merge(void **array, void **aux, int low, int mid, int high, isLess less){

  for(int index = low; index <= high; index++){
    aux[index] = array[index]; //Shallow copy
  }
  printf("Low-%d, Mid-%d, High-%d\n", low, mid, high);
  int leftIndex = low; int rightIndex = mid+1;
  printf("leftIndex-%d, rightIndex-%d\n", leftIndex, rightIndex);

  for(int index = low; index <= high; index++){

    if(leftIndex > mid)    /* right array exhausted */  array[index] = aux[rightIndex++];
    else if(rightIndex > high) /*left array exhausted*/ array[index] = aux[leftIndex++];
    else if( less(aux[rightIndex], aux[leftIndex]) )    array[index] = aux[rightIndex++];
    else                                                array[index] = aux[leftIndex++];
  }
}


static void insSort(List *list, size_t listSize, isLess less){

  for(int sortedBoundaryIndex = -1; sortedBoundaryIndex < (long long)listSize - 1; sortedBoundaryIndex++){
    /*
      -1 mean sorted pool is yet to form.
       0 mean first element is in sorted pool
    */

    for(int unSortedElementIndex = sortedBoundaryIndex + 1; unSortedElementIndex > 0; unSortedElementIndex--){
      /* Within this loop, sorted pool does not exist, as new element is being compared*/
      if(less(list->array[unSortedElementIndex], list->array[unSortedElementIndex-1])){
        arraySwap(list, unSortedElementIndex, unSortedElementIndex-1);
      }else{
        break; //If the unsorted element is > or ==, no swap, Stable sort
      }
    }
  }
}

static void *bSearchIter(const void *key, void **array, int lowerBound, int upperBound, compareTo compare){

  int mid =0;
  while(lowerBound <= upperBound){

    mid = (lowerBound + upperBound)/2;

    if(compare(key, array[mid]) == 0){

      return array[mid];
    }else if(compare(key, array[mid]) < 0){
      upperBound = mid-1;
    }else if(compare(key, array[mid]) > 0){
      lowerBound = mid + 1;
    }
  }/* end while */

  return NULL;
}

static void *bSearchRecur(const void *key, void **array, int lowerBound, int upperBound, compareTo compare){

  if(lowerBound > upperBound) return NULL;

  int mid = (lowerBound + upperBound)/2;

  if(compare(key, array[mid]) == 0){

    return array[mid];
  }else if(compare(key, array[mid]) < 0){

    return bSearchRecur(key, array, lowerBound, mid-1, compare);
  }else { // compare() > 0

    return bSearchRecur(key, array, mid+1, upperBound, compare);
  }
}


/* resizeList() is not visible to Linker (ld) */
static List *resizeList(List *list, ListResizeOperation opType){

  if(opType == DOUBLE_THE_LIST){

    list->array = realloc(list->array, 2*(list->size)*sizeof(void *));
    if(list->array == NULL){ return NULL; }
    list->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    list->size = 2*(list->size);
  }else if(opType == HALF_THE_LIST){

    list->array = realloc(list->array, ((list->size)/2)*sizeof(void *));
    if(list->array == NULL){ return NULL; }
    list->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;
    list->size = (list->size)/2;
  }

  return list;
}

/************* helper symbols - end  ************/

/* config.c requires below symbol */
ListHandler arrayImplHandler = {
  canArrayImplHandle,
  arrayCreate,
  arrayFree,
  arraySwim,
  arraySink,
  arrayDeleteMaxElement,
  sortedArrayDeleteMaxElement,
  arrayGetSize,
  arrayGetItem,
  sortedArrayInsertItem,
  arrayInsertItem,
  arrayDeleteItem,
  arrayDeleteLastItem,
  arrayDeleteFirstItem,
  arrayLinearSearch,
  arrayBinarySearch,
  arrayInsertionSort,
  arrayMergeSort,
  arraySwap,
};
```

---

## linkedListImpl.c

```
/**********linkedListImpl.c ***********/


#include"list/listHandler.h" // for 'ListHandler' type

  /* typedef is alway local to file */
  typedef struct DListNode DListNode;

  /******Private symbol - start - Not visible to linker *****/
  static DListNode* createNode(void *);
  /******Helper function - end ******************/

/***************** Representation - start ******************/

  /* Private structure */
  typedef struct DListNode{
    void *item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  }Node;



  /*
    Reason to introduce 'List' type:

    Problem 1:
     Say, user code has 'x' and 'y' pointing to the same shopping list that is built using 'Node' type.
     Some part of user code update list with new item using 'x'
     'y' is not in sync with this updation
        Node *x = someCreatedList;
        Node *y = x;
        Node *z = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        z->next = x;
        x = z; //y misses that reference.
    Solution:
     Maintain a List type, whose job is to point to head(first node) of the list.
     User code will go via reference of List type


    Problem 2:
     It make sense to have references of 'Node' type pointing to NULL
     Applying operation[insertItem()] on NULL pointer will cause runtime errors
    Solution:
     Run operations over List type because it does not make sense to have reference of SList type pointing to NULL.

    To solve problem1 & problem2, here is 'List' type
  */


  /* Public structure with restricted access to user */

  typedef struct List{

    DListNode *head;
    int size; /*size attribute is not part of list definition,
               but quick way to help user code */
  }List;

#define SENTINEL_NODE_DATA_ITEM (void *)0

/************ Representation - end *************/


/****Public symbols - start **********/

bool canLinkedListImplHandle(char *argvOneOption){

  if(strcmp(argvOneOption, "LINKEDLIST") == 0){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}



List *linkListCreate(){

    /*
      Amidst performing insert/delete operations on 'List',
      To reduce the number of special checks, we designate one node as 'SENTINEL'
      After using sentinel, there will be no NULL assignments/check in code.
    */
    List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if(list != NULL){

      DListNode *sentinel = createNode(SENTINEL_NODE_DATA_ITEM);
      list->head = sentinel;
      list->head->next = list->head;
      list->head->prev = list->head;
      list->size = 0;

      return list;
    }else{

      return NULL;
    }
}

void linkListFree(List *list){

  if(list != NULL){
    if(list->size > 0){

      int index = 0;
      DListNode *currentNode, *nextNode;
      currentNode = list->head->next;
      do{
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        free(currentNode->item);
        free(currentNode);
        currentNode = nextNode;
      }while(++index < list->size);
      return;
    }else{

      return;
    }
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to free()\n");
    return;
  }
}


void linkListSwim(List *list, int index, isLess less){

  return;
}


void linkListSink(List *list, int parentIndex, isLess less){

  return;
}

void * linkListDeleteMaxElement(List *list, isLess less){

  return NULL;
}


void* sortedLinkListDeleteMaxElement(List *list){

  return NULL;
}


int linkListGetSize(List *list){

  if(list != NULL){
    return list->size;
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr, "List is NULL\n ");
    return -1;
  }
}

const void *linkListGetItem(List *list, int index){

  if((index >=0) && (index < list->size)){

    DListNode *node = list->head->next;
    while(index-- > 0){
      node = node->next;
    }
    return (const void *)node->item;
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid index \n");
    return NULL;
  }
}

/* O(1) operation - insert() operation */
void linkListInsertItem(List *linkedList, void *newItem){

  DListNode *newNode = createNode(newItem);
  if(linkedList->size == 0){

    linkedList->head->next = linkedList->head->prev = newNode;
  }else{

    /* Link with current last node in the linked list*/
    newNode->prev = linkedList->head->prev;
    linkedList->head->prev->next = newNode;

    /* Link with Sentinel node */
    newNode->next = linkedList->head;
    linkedList->head->prev = newNode;
  }
  linkedList->size++;

}

List* sortedLinkListInsertItem(List *list, void *item, compareTo compare){

  return NULL;
}


       /* O(n) - delete() operation*/
void *linkListDeleteItem(List *linkedList, int listIndex){

  int nodeIndex = 0;
  DListNode *nodeToDelete = linkedList->head->next;

  if(listIndex < linkedList->size){

     while(nodeIndex++ < listIndex){
      nodeToDelete = nodeToDelete->next;
     }
     nodeToDelete->prev->next = nodeToDelete->next;
     nodeToDelete->next->prev = nodeToDelete->prev;

     linkedList->size++;

     void *item = nodeToDelete->item;
     free(nodeToDelete);
     return item; /* User must delete free(item); */
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "linkListDeleteItem() - List is empty");
    return NULL;
  }
}


/* O(1) - deleteLastItem() operation */
void *linkListDeleteLastItem(List *linkedList){

  if(linkedList->size){

    DListNode *nodeToDelete = linkedList->head->prev;
    void *item = nodeToDelete->item;
    nodeToDelete->prev->next = nodeToDelete->next;
    nodeToDelete->next->prev = nodeToDelete->prev;

    free(nodeToDelete);
    return item; /* User must free this item,by casting, free(item) */
  }else{

    return NULL;
  }
}

/* O(1) - deleteFirstItem() operation */
void *linkListDeleteFirstItem(List *linkedList){

  if(linkedList->size){

    DListNode *nodeToDelete = linkedList->head->next;
    void *item = nodeToDelete->item;
    nodeToDelete->next->prev = nodeToDelete->prev;
    nodeToDelete->prev->next = nodeToDelete->next;

    free(nodeToDelete);
    return item; /* User must free this item,by casting, free(item) */
  }else{

    return NULL;
  }
}

int linkListLinearSearch(const void *keyItem, List *list, size_t listSize, compareTo compare){

  Node *nodeToSearch = NULL;
  if(listSize > 0){
    nodeToSearch = list->head->next;
  }else{
    return -1;
  }

  for(int index=0; index < listSize; index++){
    if(compare(keyItem, nodeToSearch->item) ==0){
      return index;
    }
    nodeToSearch = nodeToSearch->next;
  }
  return -1;
}


void* linkListBinarySearch(const void *key, List *list, size_t size, compareTo compare){

  return NULL;
}


void linkListInsertionSort(List *list, size_t size, isLess less){

  return;
}


void linkListMergeSort(List *list, size_t size, isLess less){

  return;
}

void linkListSwap(List *list, int i, int j){

  return;
}

/******Public symbols - end *************/


/******Private symbols - start - Not visible to linker*******/

static DListNode *createNode(void * value){

  DListNode *newNode= malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

  newNode->next = newNode;
  newNode->prev = newNode;
  newNode->item = value;

  return newNode;
}


/****Private symbols - end ********/

/* 'config.c' lookup below global symbol */
ListHandler linkedListImplHandler = {

  canLinkedListImplHandle,
  linkListCreate,
  linkListFree,
  linkListSwim,
  linkListSink,
  linkListDeleteMaxElement,
  sortedLinkListDeleteMaxElement,
  linkListGetSize,
  linkListGetItem,
  sortedLinkListInsertItem,
  linkListInsertItem,
  linkListDeleteItem,
  linkListDeleteLastItem,
  linkListDeleteFirstItem,
  linkListLinearSearch,
  linkListBinarySearch,
  linkListInsertionSort,
  linkListMergeSort,
  linkListSwap,
};
```

---

## file.h

```
#include"list/listInterface.h"

#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#define MAX_RECORD_SIZE 256
/***************Usage -start **********/
typedef void (*PrintCacheItem)(const void *);

typedef struct DBCache DBCache;

void readDataIntoCache(FILE *, DBCache *, char[], char *, char*[]);
void readHeader(FILE *, DBCache *, char[]);
DBCache* initCache(FILE *, char *[]);
List* getItemList(DBCache*);
void printCache(DBCache*, PrintCacheItem, char*[]);
void freeCache(DBCache*, char *[]);
/***************Usage - end ***********/


#endif
```

---

## fileReading.c

```
#include"fileIO/file.h"


#define MALLOC_FAILURE "malloc() failed"
#define FILE_HANDLE_FAILURE "Unable to open file"
#define DELIMITER ","


/***************Repr-start ***************/
typedef struct DBCache{
  List *records;
  char *header;
  size_t fileSize;
  char  *fileDataStream;
}DBCache;

/*************** Repr-end ******************/

static void checkHandleFailure(void *, char *);
static void noNewLine(char[]);
static void copyData(List *, char [], char *, char *[]);
/**************Usage-start **************/

List * getItemList(DBCache *cache){
  return cache->records;
}


void readDataIntoCache(FILE *pFile, DBCache *cache, char buf[], char *delim, char *argv[]){

  if(pFile == NULL){
    checkHandleFailure(pFile, FILE_HANDLE_FAILURE);
  }
  fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

  while(fgets(buf, MAX_RECORD_SIZE, pFile) != NULL){

    noNewLine(buf);

    copyData(cache->records, buf, delim, argv);

  }
}

void readHeader(FILE *pFile, DBCache* cache, char buf[]){

  if(pFile == NULL){
    checkHandleFailure(pFile, FILE_HANDLE_FAILURE);
  }

  fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

  if(fgets(buf, MAX_RECORD_SIZE, pFile) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "EOF encountered\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  noNewLine(buf);

  cache->header = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
  checkHandleFailure(cache->header, MALLOC_FAILURE);
  strcpy(cache->header, buf);
  memset(buf, 0, MAX_RECORD_SIZE);
}

DBCache *initCache(FILE *pFile, char *argv[]){

  DBCache *cache = malloc(1*sizeof(DBCache));

  checkHandleFailure(cache, MALLOC_FAILURE);

  cache->records = createList();

  checkHandleFailure(cache->records, MALLOC_FAILURE);
  cache->header = NULL;


  fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
  cache->fileSize = ftell(pFile) + 1;

  cache->fileDataStream = malloc(cache->fileSize * sizeof(char));
  fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fgets(cache->fileDataStream, cache->fileSize, pFile);
  fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
  return cache;
}

void freeCache(DBCache *cache, char *argv[]){
  printf("Before freeList()");
  freeList(cache->records);
  printf("After freeList()");
  if(cache->header != NULL)
    free(cache->header);
  free(cache->fileDataStream);
}

void printCache(DBCache * cache, PrintCacheItem printItem, char *argv[]){

  List *list = cache->records;
  for(int index =0; index < getSize(list); index++){
    getItem(list, index);
  }
  printf("Size of list: %d\n", getSize(list));
}
/***************Usage-end ***************/


/******************Helper -start ***********/

static void copyData(List *records, char buf[], char *delim, char *argv[]){

    char *token =  strtok(buf, delim);

    void *item = malloc(strlen(token) +1);
    item = memcpy(item, token, strlen(token)+1);
    //printf("token-%s\n", token);
    while(token != NULL){

      insertItem(records, item);
      token = strtok(NULL, delim);
      //printf("token-%s\n", token);
      if(token != NULL){
        item = malloc(strlen(token));
        memcpy(item, token, strlen(token)+1);
      }
    }
}

static void noNewLine(char buf[]){
  int len = strlen(buf);

  if(len > 0){
    if(buf[len-1] == '\n'){
      buf[len-1] = '\0';
    }
  }
}

static void checkHandleFailure(void *ptr, char *msg){
  if(ptr == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}


/******************Helper - end ***********/
```

---

## ST/ST.h

```
#include"list/listInterface.h"

#ifndef ST_H
#define ST_H

typedef struct ST ST;
typedef void *(*UpdateValue)(const void *, const void *);
typedef void (*PrintItem)(const void *, const void *);

ST* createST(char *[]);
void freeST(ST*, char *[]);
void *get(ST *, void *, compareTo, char *[]);
void put(ST *, void *key, void *value, compareTo, UpdateValue, char *[]);
void printKeys(ST *, PrintItem, char *[]);
#endif
```

---

## ST/implWithArray.c

```
#include"ST.h"
/******* Representation - start *************/

/*** Private key-value pair structure *******/
typedef struct{
  void *key;
  void *value;
  int (*compareKey)(const void *, const void *);
}Pair;

typedef struct ST{
  List *keyValuePairList;
}ST;
#define MALLOC_FAILURE "malloc() failed\n"
#define NULL_POINTER   "Null pointer passed\n"
/********Representation - end *************/
static Pair* createPairItem(void *, void *, compareTo);
static int compareItem(const void *, const void *);
static void *getValue(const Pair *);
static int findItemInST(ST *st, void *, compareTo, char *[]);
/***********Public symbol - start ************/

ST *createST(char *argv[]){

  ST *st = malloc(sizeof(ST));
  if(st != NULL){

    st->keyValuePairList = createList();
    return st;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, MALLOC_FAILURE);
  return NULL;
}

void freeST(ST *st, char *argv[]){

  if(st != NULL){
    freeList(st->keyValuePairList);
    free(st);
    return;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, NULL_POINTER);
}

void *get(ST *st, void *key, compareTo compareKey, char *argv[]){


  int index = findItemInST(st, key, compareKey, argv);
  if(index != -1){
    List *list = st->keyValuePairList;
    const Pair *listItem = getItem(list, index);
    return getValue(listItem);
  }
  return NULL;
}

void put(ST *st, void *key, void *value, compareTo compareKey, UpdateValue updateValue, char *argv[]){

  void *oldValue = get(st, key, compareKey, argv);
  if(oldValue != NULL){
    int index = findItemInST(st, key, compareKey, argv);
    deleteItem(st->keyValuePairList, index);
    value = updateValue(value , oldValue);
  }

  //Create Pair item only after finalising value
  void * newItem = createPairItem(key, value, compareKey);

  insertItem(st->keyValuePairList, newItem);
}

void printKeys(ST *st, PrintItem printItem, char *argv[]){
  if(st != NULL){
    List *list = st->keyValuePairList;
    for(int index = 0; index < getSize(list); index++){
      const Pair *pair = getItem(list, index);
      printItem(pair->key, pair->value);
    }
  }
}


/***********Public symbol - end************/

static int findItemInST(ST *st, void *key, compareTo compareKey, char *argv[]){

  const Pair * item = createPairItem(key, NULL, compareKey);
  List *list = st->keyValuePairList;
  int index = lSearch(item, list, getSize(list), compareItem);
  return index;
}

static void *getValue(const Pair *item){
  if(item != NULL){

    return item->value;
  }
  return NULL;
}

static Pair * createPairItem(void *key, void *value, compareTo compareKey){
  Pair *item = malloc(sizeof(Pair));
  item->key = key;
  item->value = value;
  item->compareKey = compareKey;
  return item;
}

static int compareItem(const void *item1, const void *item2){

  if(item1 != NULL && (item2 != NULL)){

    return ((Pair *)item1)->compareKey( ((Pair *)item1)->key,
                                        ((Pair *)item2)->key  );
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

## frequencyCounter.c

```
#include"ST/ST.h"
#include"fileIO/file.h"

int compareKey(const void *key1, const void *key2){

  return strcmp( (const char *)key1, (const char *)key2 );
}

void * updateValue(const void *value1, const void *value2){
 int sum = *(int *)value1 + *(int *)value2;
 int *newValue = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *newValue = sum;
 return newValue;
}

void printItem(const void *key, const void *value){
  fprintf(stdout, "Key is:'%s', ", (const char *)key);
  fprintf(stdout, "Frequency is:%d\n", *(const int *)value);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if(argc == 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "usage:\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  FILE *pFile = fopen("tinyTale", "r");
  if(pFile!= NULL){


    DBCache *cache = initCache(pFile, argv);
    char buf[MAX_RECORD_SIZE];
    readDataIntoCache(pFile, cache, buf, " ", argv);

    List *list = getItemList(cache);
    ST *st = createST(argv);
    if(st != NULL){
      int *value = malloc(sizeof(int)); *value = 1;
      for(int index =0; index < getSize(list); index++){
        printf("item:%s\n", (char *)getItem(list, index));
        put(st, (void *)getItem(list, index), value, compareKey, updateValue, argv);
      }
    }
    printKeys(st, printItem, argv);
    freeST(st, argv);
    freeCache(cache, argv);
  } //end pFile
  fclose(pFile);
}
```

---

## Compilation procedure

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -I. ./list/*.c ./fileIO/*.c ./ST/*.c frequencyCounter.c -o frequencyCounter
```

---

## Output

```
$ ./frequencyCounter.exe ARRAY
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:best
item:of
item:times
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:worst
item:of
item:times
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:age
item:of
item:wisdom
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:age
item:of
item:foolishness
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:epoch
item:of
item:belief
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:epoch
item:of
item:incredulity
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:season
item:of
item:light
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:season
item:of
item:darkness
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:spring
item:of
item:hope
item:it
item:was
item:the
item:winter
item:of
item:despair
Key is:'best', Frequency is:1
Key is:'worst', Frequency is:1
Key is:'times', Frequency is:2
Key is:'wisdom', Frequency is:1
Key is:'age', Frequency is:2
Key is:'foolishness', Frequency is:1
Key is:'belief', Frequency is:1
Key is:'epoch', Frequency is:2
Key is:'incredulity', Frequency is:1
Key is:'light', Frequency is:1
Key is:'season', Frequency is:2
Key is:'darkness', Frequency is:1
Key is:'spring', Frequency is:1
Key is:'hope', Frequency is:1
Key is:'it', Frequency is:10
Key is:'was', Frequency is:10
Key is:'the', Frequency is:10
Key is:'winter', Frequency is:1
Key is:'of', Frequency is:10
Key is:'despair', Frequency is:1
```

---

My questions:

1. Can `listInterface.h` get more readable/easy_to_use for user of `List` abstraction? Easy to use, because user of `List` abstraction has to pass its `argv` parameter to `List` public API.
2. From a code elegance aspect, can I improve `List` abstraction?
3. From a code elegance aspect, can I improve `ST` abstraction?

**Note:** Going further, multiple implementations of `ST` will adapt the same design as `List` is implemented.

Comment: Almost all of [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150830/tree-abstraction/150887#150887) still applies to this code.

Comment: @Edward Code added now. First question is crucial to proceed further coding

Comment: You say you need all that code for... `` let distinctWordCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\text.txt") |> split |> Array.distinct |> Array.length``? It is over designed and also has at least 1 memory leak (value in main). And even in C you could write all that in about 50 lines of code max. In 1 module and with maybe 2,3 functions.

Comment: @BitTickler Can you please read these 3 [comments](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339635/refactoring-list-abstraction-c#comment728489_339639)? and let me know, why should I not design `List` as it is. I cannot design `List` just for the sake of `freqCounter.exe`. It should be used for multiple clients

Comment: From where did you learn the idiom presented in `listInterface.h`, of defining forwarding macros for all of your functions, using a different name? That seems like horribly bad design to me. I would guess that you've named your functions with a `v` prefix to work around the fact that there are no namespaces in C, but then by providing these global macros, you've made the problem twice as bad! Is there are good reason why you're doing this?

Comment: @CodyGray Only mistake I made was to introduce `listInterface.h`. Basically I am on the way to do what I saw, as mentioned in my 3 comments [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339635/refactoring-list-abstraction-c#comment728489_339639). Implementing `List` is a good analogy. It is an easy fix to remove `listInterface.h`, which I can do it, unless you exaggerate the mistake i did by introducing `listInterface.h`. It is beyond comments, we can go in chatroom on knowing my goal in writing `List` abstraction this way

Comment: From an elegance aspect I would note: A) We have 2017. B) In C++ you have lists and vectors and everything in the standard library. C) it is unlikely you will make "business" with "clients" selling word frequency applications written in C. D) In higher level languages this is a 1 liner written in less than 3min. E) Maintenance: The more lines and modules you have, the more costly. F) Testing: You will need around 2x lines of unit tests for all that. -> Elegance is: If you really write it in C, use as few lines of code as you can.

Comment: @BitTickler I never had thought in my mind about less code more feature, during this implementation. It was all about inspiring from `Linux/net` source code design. @GreyBeard also suggested me to link implementations in link time

Comment: If you are on Linux simply use ``#include <Linux/list.h> and use that list (which also works in user space afaik).

Comment: @BitTickler How can you compare dynamic language syntax with static typed language(C)? What is the context that you are bringing in here?  Did you understand those 3 comments that I shared with you?

Comment: Okay. C has no templates. You try to make a science project out of a one liner. That is okay. Here is my view on things: If you want "instances" of a "generic" list in C, you better write yourself a code generator tool (in a reasonably high level language) which generates the code for the type you want. Instead of using ``#define`` stuff to "map" a concrete type to a ``void *`` which is what you basically do. If you want to do that approach in a "clever,, high tech" way, you could consider to write a llvm clang plugin which does that while running the compiler ;)

Comment: @BitTickler  I never used `#define` to map concrete type to `void *` in my code. Can you show me one line? Is it over design from me or under thinking from you?

Comment: /*********** User Interface - start *****************/
#define createList()                   vCreateList(argv[1])
#define freeList(a)                    vFreeList(a, argv[1])
#define swim(a, b, c)                  vSwim(a, b, c, argv[1])
That, for example. And all that impl layer and whatnot added complexity. You can try to hide it but you only have 2 and only 2 options: 1) Write a list for a specific type. 2) Write a void * based generic list and wrapper functions around the basic list api doing just what I said... the mapping (with additional memory management specific to the type).

Comment: @BitTickler After reading your 5th comment, I can simply suggest you to  learn C. To rephrase my point read this [comment](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339635/refactoring-list-abstraction-c#comment728498_339639). Not sure, what you are talking? Am done with these comments

Comment: Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Mast For me, that answer is Invalid and out of context from question. I informed this in my comments. Please read. I am raising moderator attention for all nuisance created by BitTickler in CR.

Comment: @overexchange it is a good answer, it's unfortunate that you don't like it, even it's actually meant to help you. I locked this question now because you repeatedly changed the code. Please stop doing that. If you would like to discuss this further, please feel free to link to this question in the 2nd Monitor chat room.

Answer (score 10):

Writing code serves multiple purposes:

- Create a solution to a problem. Here: Word frequency count.
- Write code which is maintainable. Code usually lives longer than one would hope for.
- Write code which is readable. This is specific to an intended audience. (e.g. other developers, customers, QA reviewers).
- Save (future) work, if the opportunity shows. (Reuse). Important here: Reusing a piece of code should be *easier* and *faster* and *less buggy* than writing it from scratch (maybe in a simplified version as not all the original features are required every time).

Now, let us assume the intended audience is a (future) developer who hopes to get their new work done more quickly and in a higher quality by reusing the list implementation shown in the question. Lets also assume, the target platform etc. are the same (whole new ball game, if not, e.g desktop -> embedded or user space -> kernel space).

The first question a potential re-user of this list implementation might ask is: What kind of list is this? Singly linked, double linked? The name says nothing about it.

-> First improvement: As it is supposed to be a doubly linked list, name it accordingly. List is too general. As with the type of list come the trade offs. (Cheap or expensive to append at the end? ... ).

Now, the potential re-user will ask next: Okay I need it for another list element type. What do I have to do? Because the main use case is usually not to change the implementation of the list behind an interface but to use the list for a new element type. Probably the best hint to that question can be found in `ST.h` as it appears to be some kind of "list consumer layer", even though the naming is dubious (What does ST stand for?).

There is, of course nothing wrong with writing a list implementation only using `void *` as element type (except, the extra allocations required, compared to a dedicated, element type specific list implementation).

So, lets have a closer look at the "generic" doubly linked list interface, next...

```
#define createList()                   vCreateList(argv[1])
#define freeList(a)                    vFreeList(a, argv[1])
#define swim(a, b, c)                  vSwim(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define sink(a, b, c)                  vSink(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define deleteMax(a, b)                vListDeleteMaxElement(a, b, argv[1])
#define sortDeleteMax(a)               vSortedListDeleteMaxElement(a, argv[1])
#define getSize(a)                     vListGetSize(a, argv[1])
#define getItem(a, b)                  vListGetItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define sortInsertItem(a, b, c)        vSortedListInsertItem(a, argv[1])
#define insertItem(a, b)               vListInsertItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define deleteItem(a, b)               vListDeleteItem(a, b, argv[1])
#define deleteLastItem(a)              vListDeleteLastItem(a, argv[1])
#define deleteFirstItem(a)             vListDeleteFirstItem(a, argv[1])
#define lSearch(a, b, c, d)            vLinearSearch(a, b, c, d, argv[1])
#define bSearch(a, b ,c, d)            vBinarySearch(a, b, c, d, argv[1])
#define callInsertionSort(a, b, c)     vInsertionSort(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define callMergeSort(a, b, c)         vMergeSort(a, b, c, argv[1])
#define swap(a, b, c)                  vSwap(a, b, c, argv[1])
```

As, for example pointed out in the classic book "Writing solid code", interfaces shall be complete *and* minimal.

As such, methods like `bSearch, lSearch, callInsertionSort, callMergeSort, swim, sink (??!!)` violate the minimalism requirement for interfaces. Some of them are convenience functions (which increase maintenance work), some of them are not even likely to be implemented with the implied performance traits. (Binary search on a linked list?!).

-> Second Improvement: Remove all non-minimal functions from the interface.

### Naming

Most programmers have used lists before. Either in other languages or in similar languages. To speed up their learning curve, it is best to use names which are commonplace for commonplace operations. So, instead of inventing new names, it is better to google e.g. std::list and re-use those names given there. Even if the C- functions are likely to have another signature (no exceptions..), it is still easier for new programmers to find what they are looking for.

Also, it is good to give function pairs (e.g. CreateList(), FreeList()) consistent naming which denotes the antagonist role of those functions. So it would rather be `CreateList(), DestroyList()` or `AllocList(),FreeList()` or maybe even `InitializeList(), UninitializeList()` or re-using C++ terminology, `ConstructList(), DestructList()`.

### C "Interfaces" aka C-Vtables

If so inclined, a "generic" list interface can be defined as a struct of function pointers. That only is desirable if there is likely more than one implementation. If that is not really likely, it just adds complexity for potential (re-) users.

```
typedef struct IDoubleList_tag {
     bool (*ConstructList) ( DoubleList_t * );
     void (*DestructList) ( DoubleList_t *, void (*DestructElement) (void*) );
     bool (*PushFront) (DoubleList_t *, void *);
     bool (*PushBack) (DoubleList_t *, void *);
     // ...
} IDoubleList_t;
```

It should be noted, that there is an alternative for this approach which is possibly even more appealing. Instead of having structs with function pointers, if it is rather a strategic decision (for an application or library), which list implementation is preferred, a simple `DoubleList.h` file with the interface functions would do. And then, the application integrator decides which (.c) implementation file they use for their application. Much less ceremony. Much less boiler plate. Same effect. If multiple implementations are required within the same link unit (shared library, library, application,...), the user would have to have a way to choose amongst the available implementations. (How does that work here?).

In summary,

- DoubleList.h
- DoubleListImpl1.c
- DoubleListImpl2.c
- ...
  and letting the integrator decide is much easier and elegant than having the vtable-struct.

### The rule of 3

One of the golden rules in IT is the rule of 3. Just as important as the 80/20 rule. The rule of 3 addresses the question, when to start writing re-usable code. The first time, an application needs some "feature" or the second or the third time or... never? Different philosophies exist. But the most commonplace consensus is: After the third time. No one really earnestly defends the "right away" philosophy. Why is that? Because usually it takes a few applications to gain insights on the problem domain. Meaning: In the first attempt of using some "feature", it is unlikely that the interface will be well chosen for future applications. If, on the other hand 3 or more implementations exist, it is much more likely that someone can define a robust and useful and re-usable interface for that given feature.

### Other points

- The code in the question has a set of memory leaks, e.g. the `int* value ...` in main() but there were more of them in other files as well. One more reason to keep it simple and stupid: Number of bugs is proportional to lines of code.
- Some names are unfortunately chosen in the code. "DBCache" for example is misleading and not really improving readability. "DB" is associated with "Database". So any reader will be misled, starting to wonder if maybe some sick SQL database is behind all that... Cache as a word is just equally misleading. Caches "hide" (French cacher) something. What is hidden here? Caches usually pay off when the same value which is obtained expensively is used more than once (what is being frequently accessed here, justifying "caching"? Is it a form of memoization?
- A list is not even the optimal data structure for finding word frequencies. Maybe some form of Trie or a hashmap would be much better performing (O(1) lookups instead of at best (O(log n), but more likely O(n)).
- Goal confusion: The question asks about word frequencies. The first headline in the question then states it is about "Symbol Tables" (which is a term from parsing). Only to then eventually dropping all that, asking about a "List- interface" design.

### Last not least

Last not least, here the to-the metal short version of a (non-runtime optimal) word frequency counter, which is based on a 60 lines long implementation of a singly linked list. As I was too lazy to boot my Linux VM, the code contains a few windowisms which are easily removed. (first two lines for example). As well as my heap checking (#include  and CrtSetDbgFlags() in main()).

Total number of physical lines: 120. (Okay not 50 as I guessed in the comments). SLOCS probably coming close to that number, though.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY 20

static char * NextWord(FILE * fp)
{
    char * result = NULL;
    if (!feof(fp))
    {
        result = malloc(STRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        if (NULL != result)
        {
            if (0 == fscanf_s(fp,"%s",result, STRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY))
            {
                free(result);
                result = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

typedef struct ListItem_tag
{
    char * word;
    int count;
    struct ListItem_tag *pNext;
} ListItem_t;

typedef struct CountedStringList_tag
{
    ListItem_t *pHead;
} CountedStringList_t;

bool InitList(CountedStringList_t *pList)
{
    if (NULL != pList)
    {
        pList->pHead = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool AddToList(CountedStringList_t *pList, const char *word)
{
    if (NULL == pList || NULL == word)
        return false;
    ListItem_t *current = pList->pHead;
    while (NULL != current)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(word, current->word))
        {
            current->count++;
            return true;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    current = malloc(sizeof(ListItem_t));
    if (NULL != current)
    {
        current->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
        if (NULL != current->word)
        {
            strcpy(current->word, word);
            current->count = 1;
            current->pNext = pList->pHead;
            pList->pHead = current;
            return true;
        }
        free(current);
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

void FreeList(CountedStringList_t *target)
{
    ListItem_t *current = target->pHead;
    while (NULL != current)
    {
        free(current->word);
        current->word = NULL;
        ListItem_t * deleteMe = current;
        current = current->pNext;
        free(deleteMe);
    }
    target->pHead = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    const char *inputPath = "E:\\temp\\input.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(inputPath, "r");
    char *pWord = NULL;
    if (NULL != fp)
    {
        CountedStringList_t state;
        if (InitList(&state))
        {
            while (NULL != (pWord = NextWord(fp)))
            {
                //printf("%s\n", pWord);
                if (!AddToList(&state, pWord))
                {
                    puts("Failed to add to list -> aborting!");
                    return -1;
                }
                free(pWord);
            }

            for (ListItem_t *current = state.pHead; NULL != current; current = current->pNext)
            {
                printf("%s: %d\n", current->word, current->count);
            }

            FreeList(&state);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fp = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good review.  I'd like to particularly emphasize and agree with the idea that (paraphrasing) **without a clear goal, the implementation is likely to be unsatisfactory.**  I don't know what the OP is trying to do with this, and unfortunately, it's not at all clear that it would be useful for any particular purpose.

Comment: @Edward Goal is to make it maintainable.

Comment: We all want maintainable code.  As contrasted with the original code, the code in this answer is much shorter and more clear.  I'm sure you had some idea for why your code is written as it is instead of the way it's shown in this answer, but I've not been able to understand what that goal was in the four or so related questions you've asked here so far.  Sorry.

Comment: @Edward More clear? File handling/List conatiner/word count all in one file? Note in the bottom of query says, further implementations of `ST` are ahead. May be, I will learn how to write in single file after my retirement from job

Comment: My general advice is to figure out what you're trying to accomplish *first* and then worry about the physical structure of the code.  If the goal is accomplished neatly and clearly in one file, then I see no inherent problem with that.

Comment: @Edward My advice is to first accomplish reading the query properly from top to bottom including note.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51374/discussion-between-edward-and-overexchange).

Comment: @Edward What is this answer saying? *lets have a closer look at the "generic" doubly linked list interface, next...* there is no doubly link list used in this program. What is generic here? I think I had a chat, that I can [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339635/refactoring-list-abstraction-c#comment728498_339639). I don't think chat with you would be better than this. I did not down-vote this question, does not mean I agreed this answer.

Comment: @BitTickler When I write `List` abstraction, It does not convey that, binary search has to be used on linked list. It conveys that, binary search  can be performed on linked list. It is up-to the user to use binary search. Actually am wasting time here

Comment: If one gives me sorted list, I don't care whether it is array or linked list, I will search a key using binary search

Comment: Yes, only that binary search requires random access of O(1) and that is what you don't have for double linked lists. To get the nth element you need to iterate (O(N)) and that makes it a not-binary search ;)

Comment: @BitTickler Worse, the O(log n) time performance from a linked list relies on O(1) access to the i:th element, I suspect binary search on a sorted linked list would be either O(n log n) or O(n**2), both of which are worse than a simple traversal, which would be O(n).